# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Job without an ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an error that states: Couldn't find Job without an ID. The error message refers to the below coding in my application model (application.rb)

```
job = Job.find(@job_id)
```

my log in my terminal states:

> Started POST "/applications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-12 13:37:42
>   +0100 Processing by ApplicationsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"r36zBqgzp48ssfbOsl51EoKbxClr5oaogiqU9pwh/hE=",
>   "application"=>{"question"=>" I am ready to hire", "questiona"=>" I
>   own and live at this property", "jobstartdate_id"=>"", "postcode"=>"",
>   "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Next"} 
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Job without an ID):
>   app/models/application.rb:22:in `steps'
>
>   app/models/application.rb:18:in`current_step'
>   app/models/application.rb:44:in `last_step?'
>
>   app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:32:in`create'

app/controller/applications_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @applications = Application.all
  end

  def show
     @application = Application.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    session[:application_params] ||= {}
    @application = Application.new(session[:application_params])
    @application.current_step = session[:application_step]
    @application.job_id = params[:application][:job_id]
  end

  def create
    session[:application_params].deep_merge!(params[:application]) if params[:application]
    @application = Application.new(session[:application_params]) 
    @application.current_step = session[:application_step]
    if params[:previous_button]
      @application.previous_step
    elsif @application.last_step? 
      @application.save
    else
      @application.next_step
    end

    session[:application_step] = @application.current_step
    if @application.new_record?
      render :new
    else
      session[:application_step] = session[:application_params] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "Application saved"
      redirect_to @application
    end
  end
```

app/views/application/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@application) do |f| %>
  <% if @application.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@application.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this application from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @application.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "#{@application.current_step}_step", :f => f %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Back", :name => "previous_button" unless @application.first_step? %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
  </div>

  <p><%= link_to "Back to application list", applications_path %></p>

<% end %>
```

app / models / application.rb

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :phone, :email, :question, :questiona, :questionb, :postcode, :description, :job_id, :trade_id, :budget_id, :jobstartdate_id
    attr_writer :current_step, :job_id

    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :trade

    belongs_to :budget
    belongs_to :jobstartdate

    # validates :firstname, presence: true
    # validates :lastname, presence: true
    # validates :phone, presence: true
    # validates :email, presence: true

    def current_step
        @current_step || steps.first    
    end

    def steps
        job = Job.find(@job_id)
        if job.name == "Digital Home Network"
         %w[digital_Home_Network budget contact]
        else
            %w[bathroomInstallation budget contact]
        end 
    end

    def next_step
        self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]  
    end

    def previous_step
        self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]  
    end

    def first_step?
        current_step == steps.first 
    end

    def last_step?
        current_step == steps.last  
    end
end
```

Comment: where is this @job_id defined ??

Comment: Seems like your Application object never receives a @job_id. Where did you intend to set it up?

Comment: the job_id has been made as an attr_wrritter in the model (application.rb) and this is defined in the controller (application_controller.rb) as "@application.job_id = params[:application][:job_id]"

--->application_controller.rb (controller)
@application.job_id = params[:application][:job_id]

--->application.rb (model)
attr_writer :current_step, :job_id

--->method in application.rb (model)
def steps
 job = Job.find(@job_id)
 if job.name == "Digital Home Network"
  %w[digital_Home_Network budget contact]
 else
  %w[bathroomInstallation budget contact]
  end
end

Comment: hi thomas, I'm writing it in applications_controller.rb not application_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all for your response. The problem is now resolved.

In the model (application.rb) i had to the add to the create action:

> @application.job_id = params[:application][:job_id]

```
  def create
    session[:application_params].deep_merge!(params[:application]) if params[:application]
    @application = Application.new(session[:application_params]) 
    @application.current_step = session[:application_step]
    @application.job_id = params[:application][:job_id]
    if params[:previous_button]
      @application.previous_step
    elsif @application.last_step? 
      @application.save
    else
      @application.next_step
    end

    session[:application_step] = @application.current_step
    if @application.new_record?
      render :new
    else
      session[:application_step] = session[:application_params] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "Application saved"
      redirect_to @application
    end
  end
```

Then in the _form.html.erb (views/application/_form.html.erb):
i had to add a hidden field:

> 

```
<%= simple_form_for(@application) do |f| %>
  <% if @application.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@application.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this application from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @application.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :job_id, {value: @application.job_id} %>
  <%= render "#{@application.current_step}_step", :f => f %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Back", :name => "previous_button" unless @application.first_step? %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Next" %>
  </div>

  <p><%= link_to "Back to application list", applications_path %></p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access job_id as:

```
self.job_id
```

As long as it is an attribute from the model but not an initialized variable.

I rather disagree with this kind of update for the model. If you want a job to be created at the same time that an application use nested params o do a before save call. You are losing job validations, errors, and messages, an making the workflow very complex.